# how to make plot to compare rpkm values

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have a fair amount of experience analyzing RNA-Seq data, but I am looking for new ways to visualize the data. I typically use heat maps and volcano plots, but I'd like to  [make this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqGH4.png) which is from this  [paper.](https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/1471-2164-15-1078) I can make this type of plot with rlog transformed data before doing DEG analysis, but I want to color dots based on statistically significant expression differences.

I've search online and have not been able to find a good way to create this plot. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more about bioinformatics so maybe it is better you can post it on biostar.

In any case, maybe you can draw a scatter plot with the package "ggscatter" or "ggplot2" and colour the statistically significant gene with an if else statement.
Please, provide sample of your data.